# Cannot animate g class in svg using css

Tags: css, animation, svg

I've created a few lines and path in svg that I want to animate with simple transitions left and right. I created the svg in illustrator, exported and cleaned it up in my code editor, giving all g's a class name. Example:

```
<g class="T_h"><line x1="59" y1="240" x2="59" y2="285" class="style0"/></g>
```

I'm trying to animate this particular line using css;

```
@-webkit-keyframes slide {
0%   {left: 0; top:0;}
100% {left: 50px; top: 0;}
}

.T_h {
animation: slide 2s ease-in-out;
}
```

But it doesn't work. It works for div classes, but not g classes. Yet I know its possible to animate g classes, so what could be the problem?

Comment: Does `g` have `position: relative;` or `position: absolute;`? Otherwise, please try `.T_h { position: relative; animation: slide 2s ease-in-out; }`

Comment: I tried with both, but it still doesn't work!

Comment: Please show styles from `line` class `style0`.

Comment: .style0 {stroke: #FF0000; stroke-width:4; stroke-miterlimit:  10; fill: none;} (imported that way from illustrator).

Comment: I don't see how that is supposed to be valid CSS.

Comment: Maybe this will help you: https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/

Comment: Well its because this line is found in the html file within the <svg> tags, and it was just imported like that with illustrator. I could always move it to css file but bottom line is that it only sets how the line looks. I'm not sure what else could be preventing the animation from working.

Comment: `<g>` tags do not support left or top properties. You'd need to set a transform on them.

Comment: Something like this: 0%   {transform: translateX(0)}
100% {transform: translateX(100px)} within the keyframes? But that still doesn't work;;

Comment: Nevermind, I've solved it! :) All that was left to do was write '-webkit-animation:' instead of simply 'animation:' in the css for  .T_h